# How can i use multiple GSM modem to process SMS to/from a single number?

Tags: sms, modem, gsm, sms-gateway

keeping in mind that GSM modem can only process about 10 sms per minute, is there a way to use multiple modems to handle 1 number? E.g. use 10 modems to get 100 sms per minute but it's still the same number. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A single GSM Modem should have no problem recieving at least 1 SMS/second.

For multi-device bonding you would need to talk to your carriage service provider to see if that's possible.

In many countries it's probably cheaper/easier to use an IP based system if you need high throughput.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i read somewhere that "modem farms" can be used; how exactly do those work? is it what you called "multi device bonding"?

Comment: I havn't worked with more than one GSM Modem at a time, but I have worked with IP based systems (HTTP Calls, and SMPP). I'm reasonably sure though that for *recieving* more SMSs than can be supported by a single device you'd need to get the support of the carrier (so they can route/load balance SMS delivery across the GSM devices). Of course, for sending you can set the 'from' address to be any number you wish.

Comment: i see.. do you know of any good sms gateways? one which i can send and receive in the local number (e.g. i'll get a local number that my customers can send to) i asked that because a lot of companies are US and UK companies and i'm not sure if the number they provide is a US/UK number or the local number. thanks!

Comment: Most SMS Gateway providers can provide inbound SMS delivery in a dedicated number. I can't recommend any US/UK gateways - but a search will surely give you a good selection.